# numpy correlation coefficient: np.dot(A, A.T) on large arrays causing seg fault

Tags: numpy, blas, dot-product

NOTE:

```
Speed is not as important as getting a final result.
However, some speed up over worst case is required as well.
```

I have a large array A:

```
A.shape=(20000,265) # or possibly larger like 50,000 x 265
```

I need to compute the correlation coefficients.

```
np.corrcoeff # internally casts the results as doubles
```

I just borrowed their code and wrote my own cov/corr not casting into doubles, since I really only need 32 bit floats.And I ditch the conj() since my data are always real.

```
cov = A.dot(A.T)/n  #where A is an array of 32 bit floats
diag = np.diag(cov)
corr = cov / np.sqrt(np.mutliply.outer(d,d))
```

I still run out of memory and I'm using a large memory machine, 264GB

I've been told, that the fast C libraries, are probably using a routine which breaks the 
dot product up into pieces, and to optimize this, the number of elements is padded to a power of 2.

I don't really need to compute the symmetric half of the correlation coefficient matrix.
However, I don't see a way to do this in reasonable amount of time doing it "manually", with python loops.

Does anybody know of a way to ask numpy for a decent dot product routine, that balances memory usage with speed...?

Cheers

UPDATE:

Funny how writing these questions tends to help me find the language for a better google query.

Found this:

```
http://wiki.scipy.org/PerformanceTips
```

Not sure that I follow it....so, please comment or provide answers about this solution, your own ideas, or just general commentary on this type of problem.

TIA

EDIT:  I apologize because my array is really much bigger than I thought. 
array size is actually   151,000 x 265
I''m running out of memory on a machine with 264 GB with at least 230 GB free.

I'm surprised that the numpy call to blas dgemm and being careful with C order arrays
didn't do squat.

Comment: which blas library is your numpy linked against? `np.__config__.blas_opt_info`

Comment: @jtaylor  I've read a little about this config bf, but not confident in this output's meaning:
{'define_macros': [('ATLAS_INFO', '"\\"3.8.4\\""')],
 'language': 'c',
 'libraries': ['ptf77blas', 'ptcblas', 'atlas'],

Comment: "I''m running out of memory on a machine with 264 GB with at least 230 GB free"  looks suspicious, what OS and what version of python\numpy you are using? (I mean x32 or x64?)

Answer (score 4):

Python compiled with intel's mkl will run this with 12GB of memory in about 30 seconds:

```
>>> A = np.random.rand(50000,265).astype(np.float32)
>>> A.dot(A.T)
array([[ 86.54410553,  64.25226593,  67.24698639, ...,  68.5118103 ,
         64.57299805,  66.69223785],
         ...,
       [ 66.69223785,  62.01016235,  67.35866547, ...,  66.66306305,
         65.75863647,  86.3017807 ]], dtype=float32)
```

If you do not have access to in intel's MKL download python [anaconda](http://continuum.io/downloads) and install the accelerate package which has a trial version for 30 days or free for academics that contains a mkl compile. Various other C++ BLAS libraries should work also- even if it copies the array from C to F it should not take more then ~30GB of memory.

The only thing that I can think of that your installation is trying to do is try to hold the entire 50,000 x 50,000 x 265 array in memory which is quite frankly terrible. For reference a float32 50,000 x 50,000 array is only 10GB, while the aforementioned array is 2.6TB...

If its a gemm issue you can try a chunk gemm formula:

```
def chunk_gemm(A, B, csize):
    out = np.empty((A.shape[0],B.shape[1]), dtype=A.dtype)
    for i in xrange(0, A.shape[0], csize):
        iend = i+csize
        for j in xrange(0, B.shape[1], csize):
            jend = j+csize
            out[i:iend, j:jend] = np.dot(A[i:iend], B[:,j:jend])
    return out
```

This will be slower, but will hopefully get over your memory issues.

Comment: Good to know...will put more energy into getting MKL to work and hopefully repeat your results. THX!

Comment: Turns out MKL isn't really a solution I can use at my work place. If you noticed my recent edit, the array size is much bigger. If you'd care to run your sim again with the larger array I'd be curious what your results are. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

You can try and see if `np.einsum` works better than dot for your case:

```
cov = np.einsum('ij,kj->ik', A, A) / n
```

The internal workings of `dot` are a little obscure, as it tries to use BLAS optimized routines, which sometimes require copies of arrays to be in Fortran order, not sure if that's the case here. `einsum` will buffer its inputs, and use vectorized SIMD operations where possible, but outside that it is basically going to run the naive three nested loops to compute the matrix product.

Comment: Thanks Jaime, after I run a test using my updated research, I'll try your idea. If it saves memory and avoids a seg fault, it's a solution. Hopefully I can find a decently fast solution as well....

Comment: einsum appears to work as expected...slow but reasonable memory usage. I've studied physics and really like the notation.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:  Turns out the dot product completed with out error, but upon careful inspection
the output array consists of zeros at 95,000 to the end,  of the 151,000 cols.
That is, out[:,94999] = non-zero  but out[:,95000] = 0 for all rows...

This is super annoying...

[Another Blas description](http://www.marshut.com/irtskk/using-gemm-with-specified-output-array.html)

The exchange, mentions something that I thought about too...Since blas is fortran, shouldn't
the order of the input be F order...? Where as the scipy doc page below, says C order.

Trying F order caused a segmentation fault. So I'm back to square one.

ORIGINAL POST
I finally tracked down my problem, which was in the details as usual.

I'm using an array of np.float32 which were stored as F order. I can't control the F order to my knowledge, since the data is loaded from images using an imaging library.

```
import scipy
roi = np.ascontiguousarray( roi )# see roi.flags below
out = scipy.linalg.blas.sgemm(alpha=1.0, a=roi, b=roi, trans_b=True)
```

This level 3 blas routine does the trick. My problem was two fold:

```
roi.flags
C_CONTIGUOUS : False
F_CONTIGUOUS : True
OWNDATA : True
WRITEABLE : True
ALIGNED : True
UPDATEIFCOPY : False
```

And... i was using  blas dgemm NOT sgemm.  The 'd' is for 'double' and 's' for 'single'.
See this pdf: [BLAS summary pdf](http://www.netlib.org/blas/blasqr.pdf)

I looked at it once and was overwhelmed...I went back and read the wikipedia article on blas routines  to understand level 3 vs other levels: [wikipedia article on blas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Linear_Algebra_Subprograms#Functionality)

Now it works on A = 150,000 x 265, performing:

```
A \dot A.T
```

Thanks everyone for your thoughts...knowing that it could be done was most important.

Comment: I do not understand your comment `numpy.dot` correctly chooses the correct BLAS routine `DGEMM`, `SGEMM`, `CGEMV`, or whatever.

Comment: if you have a lot of zeros you can use sparse matrices http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html